# How to override .html and .js files in app/design from my custom module in app/code

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, overrides, html

Is there any way to override .html and js files present in app/design folder from a custom module in app/code ?

I was looking to override `app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html` and `app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js` from my custom module in app/code.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since app/design has the highest priority, you won't be able to override the same in your custom module.

Another way to do this would be:

1. Remove file from design
2. Add the same file in the design folder into your custom module &
   then do your required set of changes to the same.